# What is the additive inverse of $\langle x-2\rangle+(x^2-2)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x-2\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this correctly, but this is what I did:

$\langle x-2 \rangle +(x^2-2) = x^2-2$ (since here, $\langle x-2 \rangle$ is equivalent to $0$) whose additive inverse is $2-x^2$

The book (A First Course in Abstract Algebra 2nd ed. by Anderson and Feil) says the answer should be $\langle x-2 \rangle + (2-x^2)$. Do I need the $\langle x-2 \rangle$ part?

Comment: Since you're in the quotient group, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the notation you are using. $\langle x-2\rangle + (2-x^2)$ means the coset of $(2-x^2)$ in the quotient group $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x-2\rangle$. Some authors write this in short hand as $(2-x^2)$, where it is understood that this is an element of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x-2\rangle$, meaning that $(2-x^2)$ is well defined up to adding elements of the ideal $\langle x-2\rangle$.